# How to make grid row the height of the shortest child?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a grid with two columns, and two rows.

Here is the CSS that defines the layout. (the row gets its height automatically as of now)

```
grid-template-areas: 
            "main side2"
            "side1 side1"
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
```

How can I make the `side2` element the height of `main`? Main is dynamically sized, so I can't use a pixel value. The contents of `side2` uses a scrollbar when the height is capped, so changing its height is no problem.

Here is an image of the layout. The bottom element is out of frame, but it fills both the columns.

[image: Image where one column is way taller than the other]

Comment: `contain: size` to side2